# Unserialize wordpress database to query data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress, custom-taxonomy

I have a mysql database that looks like this

```
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | field_id | user_id |              value               |    last_updated     |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |       1 | admin                            | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
|  3 |        5 |       1 | a:1:{i:0;s:2:"18";}              | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
|  4 |        1 |       2 | testuser1                        | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
|  5 |        5 |       2 | a:2:{i:0;s:2:"19";i:1;s:2:"18";} | yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss |
+----+----------+---------+----------------------------------+---------------------+
```

I understand that a normal sql query will not be suitable so instead I need to pull all the data into php to then sort through it.

What I want is to get any user_id that has a number, lets say "19" in `field_id` 5. In that example, the array should read "2". Or I could search for "18" in `field_id` 5 and the array would return "1,2".

To get the database, I am using the following

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_data";
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );

$strDB = maybe_unserialize( $retrieve_data);
echo print_r($strDB, true);
?>
```

Which returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [field_id] => 1 [user_id] => 1 [value] => admin [last_updated] => 2017-09-21 12:38:20 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [field_id] => 5 [user_id] => 1 [value] => a:1:{i:0;s:2:"18";} [last_updated] => 2017-09-21 12:38:20 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [field_id] => 1 [user_id] => 2 [value] => testuser1 [last_updated] => 2017-09-23 01:43:50 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [field_id] => 5 [user_id] => 2 [value] => a:2:{i:0;s:2:"19";i:1;s:2:"18";} [last_updated] => 2017-09-23 01:43:50 ) )
```

I can't work out how I can then sort through this data. I tried to find sections of string but this was not working.

Comment: Do you need to do this directly through SQL? You would usually query a WP database using WP_Query, and I can show you how to do it that way :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I don't think I need to do it in this way, that seems to just be the path I've gone down. If there's a better way to do it using `wp_query` please enlighten me! As I said, ultimately I want the selected usernames into an array so I can use that in another function

Comment: Can you let me know exactly what you are trying to get, e.g. just the user_id, or are you ultimately trying to get user info/posts/ etc for specific users?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I want just the user_ids that match a variable number. For example, "18" in `field_id` to return an array of user_ids that would be `1,2`. When I have the array of user_ids I want to send them a private message in buddypress. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about using BuddyPress in WP_Query (I didn't notice that was what you were querying at first) but I've included hoe you should be able to do it in SQL... let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the LIKE comparison on the 'value' field, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name AND value LIKE '%9%'
```

The difficulty with searching for a number is that LIKE will also return partial matches, so a query for 9 would also return 19, 91, 192 etc.

However, based on the values getting surrounded by double quoted in the serialised string, you should be able to search for the exact value by including the double quotes in the search string, e.g. `"9"`.

Adding that into the code in your question, we get:

```
global $wpdb;

$num_to_find = 19; /* or change to whatever number you need */
$field_id_to_check = 5; /* or change to whatever number you need */

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "bp_xprofile_data";

$user_ids = $wpdb->get_results( 
     $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT user_id FROM $table_name 
                 WHERE field_id = %d AND value LIKE '%%\"%d\"%%'", 
        $field_id_to_check, /*this param replaces the 1st %d in the query */
        $num_to_find /*this param replaces the 2nd %d in the query */
    )
);
print_r($user_ids);
```

Note: because the query includes a variable and I don't know where its coming from, I've used $wpdb->prepare to sanitise the variable.

That's not tested, but I believe it should work!

Comment: Thanks. My understanding of buddypress is that once I have an array of user_ids, I can add that array into a function to send messages. What I had tried doing was this: https://pastebin.com/9d5LdEjg but it would return an empty array. I think that was because it was serialized data.

Comment: Well that code *should* return an array of user_ids, but like I said its not tested so give it a go and see if it returns what you need!

Comment: I think I must be using it wrong. How do I invoke it? As in, where do I put the number I am searching for. I'm guessing I need to tell it `$num_to_find` but can't work out how.

Comment: Also, do I need to be explicit and say `WHERE field_id = 5 AND value LIKE.......`? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know... I only wrote the query to work with what you asked for :) It depends on your setup and what you need. How do you know what the num_to_find should be when you were giving your examples? If you need to check for the field_id, just add it to the query - I'd imagine you should have it but again I'm not sure what any of those ids represent so I can't really tell :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound short! I'm really grateful for your help. It works as expected when I change `'%%\"%d\"%%'"` to `'%%\"19\"%%'"`. How do I say something like `%d = 19`?

Comment: @redditor No, you didn't sound short! I hope I didn't either :) You just need to set the value of the `$num_to_find` variable to whatever number you want e.g. 19. The "prepare" replaces the `%d` with the value of the variable in the parameter (i.e. $num_to_find) after checking that it really is a number (%d represents a number, %s is a string). This is to prevent SQL injection etc. I'll update the code to include this, and also add field_id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first rule – you should not do this. But if there is good reason, consider using such query for **searching in index-based arrays**

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE value REGEXP '.*;s:[0-9]+:"19".*'
```

Here we search on the column **value** the value ***"19"*** as you did on the example with a regex.
Regards.